# How to lay out nodes in a filled in circle in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

In Gephi, when I apply Fuchterman Reignold to a graph with almost no edges, I get something like this:

[image: gephi]

When I use networkx to draw the same graph using `spring_layout`, the center of the circle tends to be much more empty:

[image]

How can I make the networkx layout look more like the gephi layout without positioning each node by myself?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm implemented in `gephi` seems to have a `gravitation` parameter (if I understood this [parameter correctly](https://gephi.org/users/tutorial-layouts/), it is exactly designed to hold everything together), which the `networkx` algorithm does not have.

You may try to add a node, which is connected to every other with a small weight. Thus, pulling all nodes to him (which will be probably somewhere near the center).

Comment: (I assume you meant "which the `networkx` algorithm does **not** have")?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact layouts in networkx. You can use:

[spring_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout) (if you have edges between nodes, there will be in center):

[image]

or [graphviz_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout) with `prog='neato'` or `prog='fdp'`:

[image]